# MVC 4 with Google Charts API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I have a chart using Google Charts API, I can display information directly from my view but I want to send the information from the controller, so far I have tried to send the information as Json, The problem is that the chart is being displayed but its all gray and doesnt really shown any information, it just says Other. is there anything I am missing? my controller is

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetDataAssets()
        {
            List<object> data = new List<object>();
            data.Add(new[] { "Task", "Hours per Day"});
            data.Add(new[] { "Introduction", "100" });
            data.Add(new[] { "Basic 1", "75" });
            data.Add(new[] { "PHP", "24" });
            return Json(data);
        }
```

and in my view I have this

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {


        $.post('GetDataAssets', {}, function (d) {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);

     // Create and draw the visualization.
            new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(data, { title: "Top Videos", pieHole: 0.4 });
        }
    )
    };

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>

<div  id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: auto"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post the value of `d` in the above code? I'll bet your data's formatted poorly.

Comment: I print d to console, this is what I see

Array[4]
0: Array[2]
0: "Task"
1: "Hours per Day"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[2]
0: "Introduction"
1: "100"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
2: Array[2]
0: "Basic 1"
1: "75"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
3: Array[2]
0: "PHP"
1: "24"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I had to rethink the way to do it, instead of sending the JSON I'm sending it to then build the chart information, Here is what I did:

Controller:

```
public class PieChart
{
    public string Name;
    public decimal valor;
}

public ActionResult GetData()
{
    return Json(CreateDataList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public IEnumerable<PieChart> CreateDataList()
{
    List<PieChart> data = new List<PieChart>();
    PieChart r = new PieChart() { Name = "Introduction", valor = 20 };
    PieChart r1 = new PieChart() { Name = "Basic 1", valor = 24 };
    PieChart r2 = new PieChart() { Name = "PHP", valor = 74 };

    data.Add(r);
    data.Add(r1);
    data.Add(r2);

    return data;
}
```

And on the View

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function drawVisualization() {
    $.get('GetData', {}, function (data) {
        var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        tdata.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        tdata.addColumn('number', 'Hours');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tdata.addRow([data[i].Name, data[i].valor]);
        }

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(tdata, { title: "Top Videos", pieHole: 0.4 });


    })
};

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script>
```

Comment: Couple of questions if you don't mind.  The class PieChat isn't a controller so how does this part work ?   $.get('GetData'   Also, what does the new controller code look like?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, if you still need the information, it looks like this: 

on the controller I created this:

public virtual ActionResult GetPieData()
        {
            return Json(CreatePieList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: and then the CreatePieList(), still on the controller:

public IEnumerable<PieChart> CreatePieList()
        {
                        
            List<PieChart> data = new List<PieChart>();

               var newdata = createnewPieChart();
                data.Add(newdata);
            }

           
            return data;
        }

Comment: the PieChart object looks like this:

public class PieChart
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
                        
        }

Comment: need to have element with id visualization to display graph, need to include  `google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });` inside the JavaScript of View or even the return result of GetData should be JsonResult